# Connecting to WSS with websocat in Android

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, socat, self-signed-certificate

I need to connect to a WSS server that uses a self-signed certificate from an Android device with websocat.

`websocat wss://example.com` works fine with ceriticates signed with authorities, but fails to verify self-signed certificates.

There is a workaround using socat in addition to websocat:

`websocat --binary --ws-c-uri=wss://example.com - ws-c:cmd:'socat - ssl:example.com:443,verify=1,cafile=/path/to/cert.crt'`

This works in Debian, but it does not in Android, as socat for Android does not support SSL (I am not sure if there is a feasible way of compiling socat with SSL support for Android).

Is it possible to get websocat working with self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 1):

There is already `websocat 1.2.0` which supports `-k` (`--insecure`) option that, like in curl, turns off certificate verification.

Additionally I [made](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203065/5387) static-ish `openssl` executables for Android which also can be used as a workaround method in websocat 1.1.0:

```
$ websocat -b --ws-c-uri=wss://echo.websocket.org - ws-c:sh-c:'openssl s_client -quiet -connect echo.websocket.org:443'
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.websocket.org
verify return:1
dsaf
dsaf
12345
12345
```